# pgrep --count program is always returning 0, even when there obviously a instance of the program

Tags: node.js, bash, raspbian

I have a app which restart itself on error.

Since the initializing can take some time, I use a other application to play a loading video.

Since the initializing depend on internet connection, it can restart a lot of time, so I need to start the video once, after checking if a instance of the program is not already started.

I thought I could do so like this:

```
var arg = 'pgrep --count omxplayer | echo $?';
exec( arg, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    var data = '' + stdout[0];
    console.log(data);
    if (data === '0') {
        callback(true);
    } else {
        callback(false);
    }
});
```

The callback start omxplayer if the argument is false.

Problem is, when I look at my log, I can see that data is always 0, which make the app start as much of omxplayer as there is restart.

I have the same problem with `pkill -0 omxplayer | echo $?`

How can I check if omxplayer is running or not? Or how do I fix my code?

Comment: Try doing a `pgrep -lv omxplayer` while omxplayer is active, you should see it in the list that is returned.  Then you can see why it's not matching, there may be a case mismatch to where you need to do `pgrep -i --count omxplayer`

Comment: `pgrep -lv omxplayer` give me a list of process, but there is no omxplayer or whatever near that... I know omxplayer start omxplayer.bin, that s odd, I ll look that way

Comment: v invert the result, without it I do get a omxplayer process

Comment: and i flag seems to do not exist on my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, the error was not in pgrep, but on how I handled stdout.

stdout[0] seems to don t do anything, and data[0] neither.

How I was supposed to get it was data.charAt(0), which return '0' only when there is no omxplayer started.

```
var arg = 'pgrep --count omxplayer | echo $?';
exec( arg, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    var data = '' + stdout;
    data = data.charAt(0);
    console.log(data);
    if (data === '0') {
        callback(true);
    } else {
        callback(false);
    }
});
```